# How to Change the Color Palette of Atoms in ASE GUI

Tags: atomic-simulation-environment, visualization-software, software-assistance

I know that there is a configuration file called `gui.py` that would be initialized if it is placed in a directory like `~/.ase/gui.py` I use that file to change simple things in the view such as:

```
gui_default_settings['gui_foreground_color'] = '#ffffff' #white
gui_default_settings['gui_background_color'] = '#000000' #black
```

The default color palette in ase seems to be Jmol and one can adjust the color based either on atomic number or number of neighbours.
I want to change the default colors of atoms when displayed with ase gui by having my own color palette, if that is possible then how to do it or is there some other approach?